# How to use Glider image loader

Tags: android, android-imageview

I use Glider Image Loader to load icon into `ImageView` from Server. How to detect the server image has been changed when the `uri` is same?

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

hmm...

you means, real time changing image which use same url?

if it right, you need to has socket in your server

search android socket or [yourserver] socket in google

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I mean,  not really need real time, if activity restart the image, the image get update will do. I'm using Glider Image Loader library. No sure where to detect if the server image updated. Because it has been cache in local storage.